# Locating a memory leak in Android

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-context

I have an activity that sets the content view to a custom view and passes the context to it. From there multiple objects are instantiated by passing the context to their constructors. As i play my game the memory usage goes up and up starting at around 7mb going all the way to 60 or so before crashing and freezing. I was wondering how can i locate this memory leak and what are the rules on passsing the context from class to class without leaking it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How are you currently passing context ?

Comment: as a parameter when i create the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the steps [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html) to analyze your memory usage.